# how to handle GeoLocation columns in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, geolocation

I am doing predicting adduction probability drug. I have some problem with GeoLocation  column and also  I don't know how to handle with GeoLocation, please help me how to show the probability of peoples in particular locations.
my column like this :
 here my googlecolab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qM8LkkVex6cHRVXwqI40b44ofk7CmQVi

```
   train['GeoLocation'].head(8)
     0                      (29.760427, -95.369803)
1                      (29.760427, -95.369803)
2    (39.493240390000494, -117.07184056399967)
3      (40.79373015200048, -77.86070029399963)
4                      (37.77493, -122.419416)
5                      (39.952584, -75.165222)
6                     (32.715738, -117.161084)
7    (39.360700171000474, -111.58713063499971)
Name: GeoLocation, dtype: object
```

Comment: Saying it's for "Machine learning" doesn't really help explain what you want to do with this data. I would *definitely* split this data out into two columns so you can work with it more easily, but you need to be more clear.

Comment: What "problem" do you have? What is the whole set of data you are using? Could you show an input and an expected output? There is too little information in your question..

Comment: please specify *exactly* what problem you have: what "isn't working"?

Comment: hi anono, my problem is how to convert GeoLocation  object data into numeric

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the Pandas dataframe to store the geolocation. If you are interested in doing operations on the coordinates(such as distance between two, nearest city, address extraction, etc) you can either directly use the [python client library to access Google Maps APIs](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) or you can use some wrapper library to easily perform simple tasks. You can also take a look at the other maps services, but IMO and past experiences, Google maps was the most precise.

P.S. Please provide more details of the problem. What exactly are you trying to do?

I think you already know this, a geolocation field consists of - (latitude, longitude) which can precisely store the required location.